# Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, api, error-handling

I am using python 3.8.0 and Pycharm. When I try to install this API `pip install telnyx` 
it give me this error `Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

I checked around stackoverflow and github and didn't found a solution to resolve the problem... Thank you

Comment: i also have this issue, nothing on github seemed to help.

Comment: What’s the error message above? For me it was “Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH” which meant I had to install `make` (in debian it was `apt install build-essential`)